# Latinizing the surname "De Vincenzo"

Tags: names, latinization

Hello how would someone Latinize this surname? ***De Vincenzo***
Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are often several ways to Latinise a name. Could you tell us anything about the origin of the name? Is it based on the name of a location, something else? "De" suggests a location in Italian, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Also, are you looking for Classical, Medieval, or Neo-Latin ways of Latinizing? Would you prefer an etymological rendering, or just how a person might do it in one of the aforementioned periods. Do note that, as Cerberus says, there were more than one way to do this.

Comment: Yes the name is Italian, and I would like the Classical way of Latinizing. If you need any more info, let me know! Thanks.